# How can I run through a string's indexes and change the color of each letter?

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying to run through a string and change the color of each character using its index but I keep getting an error. Any help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<p id="text">jesus est le tout puissant</p>


<script>
    var text = document.getElementById("text").textContent;
    console.log(text);
    var colors = ["#EF5350","#8BC34A","#69F0AE","#FFC107","#FFD600","#4E342E","#F44336","#E91E63","#9C27B0","#F50057"];
    for(var i =0; i <= text.length; i++) {
     text[i].style.color = colors[i];
    }





</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is each letter in its own container?

Answer (score 2):

You have to treat the characters as distinct from DOM elements. As others said, wrap each letter in a `<span>`.

```js
var element = document.getElementById('text');
var text = element.textContent;
console.log(text);
var colors = ["#EF5350","#8BC34A","#69F0AE","#FFC107","#FFD600","#4E342E","#F44336","#E91E63","#9C27B0","#F50057"];
var styledText = '';
for(var i =0; i < text.length; i++) {
    styledText += '<span style="color:' + colors[i%colors.length] + '">' + text[i] + '</span>';
}
element.innerHTML = styledText;
```

```html
<p id="text">jesus es le tout puissant</p>
```

Some notes: you want `i < text.length`, not `i <= text.length`. I also used the `i%colors.length` as the index of `colors` so you loop back to the start when you run out.

Comment: Points for mentioning the modulus!

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap every letter inside a `<span>` in order to apply custom CSS to each letter. Otherwise it's all just plain text content, and nothing more.

Wrap every letter in its own `<span>`, and then iterate over each `<span>` inside the `#text` tag, and apply the CSS in the same way as in your example.

```
const colors = ["#EF5350","#8BC34A","#69F0AE","#FFC107","#FFD600","#4E342E","#F44336","#E91E63","#9C27B0","#F50057"];
const text = document.getElementById(”text”);
const letters = text.textContent;

const _fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

for (let i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
    const letter = document.createElement(”span”);
        letter.textContent = letters[i];
        letter.style.color = colors[i % colors.length]; // This makes sure to keep repeating through the colors, no matter the length of the text

    _fragment.appendChild(letter);
}

text.innerHTML = ””; // There are faster and more efficient ways to do this particular step
text.appendChild(_fragment);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can insert each single character into a SPAN and then color the individual characters through a FOR loop

```js
var colors = ["#EF5350","#8BC34A","#69F0AE","#FFC107","#FFD600","#4E342E","#F44336","#E91E63","#9C27B0","#F50057"];

var e = $('#text');
var temp = $('<span/>'); // I create a temporary font for saving characters

for (var i = 0; i < e.text().length; i++) temp.append($('<span/>').text(e.text().charAt(i)).css('color',colors[ i % colors.length])); // I separate each single letter and apply the colors

e.html(temp.html()); // Apply the changes made
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="text">jesus es le tout puissant</p>
</body>
</html>
```